# Mixitup filter in select tag is not working in google chrome and IE

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, google-chrome

I filter the mixitup in html select tag. In mozilla its working but other browser like chrome is not working. Code like -

```
<select name="" id="" class="form-control">
    <option class="filter" data-filter="all" value="">Show All</option>
    <option class="filter" data-filter=".category-1" value="">Category 1</option>
    <option class="filter" data-filter=".category-2" value="">Category 2</option>
</select>

<div id="container">
    <div class="mix category-1" data-myorder="1">
        <img src="http://revistasindromes.com/images/100x100.gif" />
    </div>
    <div class="mix category-2" data-myorder="2">
        <img src="http://revistasindromes.com/images/100x100.gif" />
    </div>
    <div class="mix category-1" data-myorder="3">
        <img src="http://revistasindromes.com/images/100x100.gif" />
    </div>
    <div class="mix category-2" data-myorder="4">
        <img src="http://revistasindromes.com/images/100x100.gif" />
    </div>
</div>
```

demo link: http://jsfiddle.net/zinannadeem/7m94mp9s/9/

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Problem is that `option` does not trigger `click` event, adding this will solve it:

```
$('.form-control').on('change', function() {
    $('.form-control option:selected').trigger('click'); 
});
```

Updated Fiddle [here](http://jsfiddle.net/7m94mp9s/10/)